How is the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact affected by the US Supreme Court's decision that states can't remove candidates from their ballot?
I was recently watching this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUX-frlNBJY) about the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact. At around the 3 minute mark, the narrator states that one of the reasons the Compact is possible is because "States can cast their Electoral College votes however they want." [Emphasis in original] My understanding (based mainly on this video) is that from the perspective of the Federal government, there's not even a requirement for a state to hold a Presidential election. The state government could simply decide which candidate to support, and give all their electoral college votes to that candidate. The only reason states are required to hold an election is because the states themselves have their own laws which require them to do so.
It's possible that the video is wrong, or that my understanding of the situation is incorrect, and if that's the case, please let me know.
However, if my understanding above is correct, then why did the US Supreme Court unanimously decide in March that states don't have the freedom to remove a Presidential candidate from their election ballot? If, from a Federal perspective, states are even allowed to go so far as to not hold an election at all, then I would think removing a candidate from the ballot would be well within the rights of a given state.
Justice Elena Kagan said: "This question of whether a former president is disqualified for insurrection, to be president again ... it sounds awfully national to me." She's right, it certainly does sound like a national question, but if my above understanding is correct, then doesn't that mean that it actually isn't a national question, but rather a state by state question?
Furthermore, how does this ruling affect the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact itself? If this ruling prevents states from removing candidates from their ballot, then could it also prevent them from casting their Electoral College votes with the candidate that wins the national popular vote, even if it goes against the votes of the state's own citizens?

AIUI, the NPVIC actually requires the states that participate in it to hold a normal election, so their votes can be counted in the popular vote.

You're right, I only used the example of not holding an election to demonstrate the wide range of freedom that states have in deciding how to distribute their Electoral College votes, although as Jen pointed out in her answer, they don't have complete freedom. It seems like the NPVIC states would still hold an election as usual.

Does this mean that theoretically a state could become a kingdom (not in name, but in function) yet still be a legal member of the Union, and the federal government would have no power in contesting it? As long as that state passes laws regarding its own elections...

@vsz The section of the constitution under discussion regards how states select electors for the Presidential election, it's not about their state governments.

In Trump v. Anderson, the Supreme Court of the United States held that  the Colorado Supreme Court erred in ordering President Trump excluded from the 2024 presidential primary ballot. The rationale was that "responsibility for enforcing Section 3 [of the 14th Amendment] against federal officeholders and candidates rests with
Congress and not the States."
The Court did not hold that States were not free to change their method of selecting electors to vote in the electoral college. The broad flexibility states have in this area is discussed at this Essay in the Constitution Annotated (it also explains that States do not have complete freedom here). I read nothing in Trump v. Anderson that would affect the viability of the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact. If there is a constitutional problem with the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact, it has nothing to do with Section 3 of the 14th Amendment.
Also, the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact doesn't envision removing candidates from the ballot, only changing the significance a state would give to the outcomes of the counts.

To further expand on Jen's answer, it is important to understand the context of the underlying Colorado decision.
Colorado did not pass a law barring Trump from the ballot. Instead, the Colorado Supreme Court ruled that Section 3 of the 14th Amendment to the (federal) Constitution had the effect of automatically barring Trump from the ballot. Because the basis of this ruling was the federal Constitution, the US Supreme Court has the authority to hear challenges over whether the Colorado Supreme Court interpreted the Constitution correctly. This authority ("jurisdiction") is granted in federal statute by 28 USC 1257, and ultimately by Article III of the US Constitution (which says among other things that "[t]he judicial Power [of the federal courts] shall extend to all Cases [...] arising under this Constitution, [...]").
Because Colorado did not pass a law barring Trump from the ballot, the Supreme Court had no occasion to consider whether such a law would be valid or not. If that hypothetical law singled out Trump by name, it might violate the Equal Protection clause of the 14th Amendment (which was the basis for SCOTUS's intervention in Bush v. Gore). To avoid this problem, we could imagine Colorado designing a process, with appropriate due process safeguards (i.e. giving Trump or any other candidate the opportunity to present evidence and arguments), that could ultimately disqualify a candidate for any lawful reason that the legislature might designate, including previous acts of insurrection against the United States. But that would also require Colorado to explicitly enact legislation barring such people from the ballot, which (again) Colorado did not do.
This case does not call into question Colorado's overall authority to determine how its elections are held, or even its authority to decide who gets to appear on the ballot. It merely calls into question the rationale that the Colorado Supreme Court relied on in their decision, which was explicitly based on a federal Constitutional issue, exactly the sort of issue that SCOTUS reviews all the time.

"If that hypothetical law singled out Trump by name, it might violate the Equal Protection clause of the 14th Amendment" Maybe a dumb question: wouldn't it more relevantly qualify as a Bill of Attainder, which the Constitution explicitly bars the states from doing in Article One? Or is there something I'm missing about what a Bill of Attainder is? I thought it was any law that targeted a specific person.

@Idran: A law may violate more than one part of the Constitution.
